# Add a custom header per rule on Kubernetes Ingress with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, request-headers

I have created a Kubernetes ingress on my cluster where it uses Istio as an ingress controller. I *don't* want to use the `gateway` and `virtual service` provided by Istio and would like to set this up with the good old Kubernetes ingress.

What I am having a hard time with is configuring a custom header to this ingress. I know with:

- Nginx ingress controller, I can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: 'more_set_input_headers "foo: bar";'`
- Traefik, I can use `ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-request-headers: "foo: bar"`

What is the corresponding annotation while using Istio? or is that even possible while using Istio this way?

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible. To add a custom header to the request, you have to add

```yaml
headers:
  request:
    add:
      custom-header: value
```

block to a *VirtualService*.

There are no [Resource Annotations](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/annotations/) in Istio that control this behaviour, like with nginx or Traefik.